# Como usar el preg_split() en PHP

Tags: php, regex

Estoy tratando de obtener SOLO EL CODIGO HTML de toda una cadena, para eso, uso esta expresión regular `/<\?php(.*)\?>/`, pero NO tengo resultados.

Me gustaría saber como puedo arreglarlo o qué otra manera hay para llegar al resultado.

**Imprimir**

```
<pre><?php var_dump($resultado) ?></pre>
```

**Este es mi script**

```
<?php
$userinfo = '<div class="contenedor-panel">
              <div class="panel-ficha">
                  <?php echo $cabecera[0]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"];?>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-aspecto">
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[1]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_gestion_educativa_1.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[2]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_gestion_educativa_2.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[3]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_gestion_educativa_3.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[4]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_gestion_educativa_4.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[5]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_gestion_educativa_5.php"; ?>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-ficha">
                  <?php echo $cabecera[6]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-aspecto">
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[7]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_promocion_educativa_zonales_1.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[8]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_promocion_educativa_zonales_2.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[9]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_promocion_educativa_zonales_3.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[10]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_promocion_educativa_zonales_4.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[11]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_promocion_educativa_zonales_5.php"; ?>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-ficha">
                  <?php echo $cabecera[12]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-aspecto">
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[13]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_coordinacion_educativa_zonales_1.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[14]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_coordinacion_educativa_zonales_2.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[15]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_coordinacion_educativa_zonales_3.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[16]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_coordinacion_educativa_zonales_4.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[17]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_coordinacion_educativa_zonales_5.php"; ?>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-ficha">
                  <?php echo $cabecera[18]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-aspecto">
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[19]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_coordinacion_academica_est_1.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[20]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_coordinacion_academica_est_2.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[21]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_coordinacion_academica_est_3.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[22]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_coordinacion_academica_est_4.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[23]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_coordinacion_academica_est_5.php"; ?>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-ficha">
                  <?php echo $cabecera[24]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-aspecto">
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[25]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_del_desempeno_docente_1.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[26]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_del_desempeno_docente_2.php"; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                      <?php echo $cabecera[27]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                      <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_del_desempeno_docente_3.php"; ?>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>';
$resultado = preg_split("/<\?php(.*)\?>/", $userinfo);
?>
<pre><?php var_dump($resultado) ?></pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agregué el código por tí en el siguiente link.

http://tpcg.io/CjIEpQ

Igual lo dejo aquí.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Online PHP Script Execution</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
    echo "<h1>Hello, PHP!</h1>\n";

    $cabecera[0]="Test";

    $userinfo = '<div class="contenedor-panel">
                     <div class="panel-ficha">
                         echo $cabecera[0]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"];
                     </div>
                 </div>';

    /*preg_match_all ("/(?< =<).php(.*).(?=>)/", $userinfo, $pat_array);*/

    echo $userinfo;

    preg_match_all ("/\<\?php(.*?)\?\>/", $userinfo, $pat_array);


   foreach($pat_array[0] as $x){
       echo "$x<br>";
       print $x."<br>";
   };

    /*print $pat_array[0][0]." <br> ".$pat_array[0][1]."\n";*/
 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Lo estoy probando en una pagina en donde puedo ejecutar codigo PHP, y los estoy intentando leer como texto plano. Aqui te dejo el link del ejercicio para que veas los resultados: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php_webview_online.php

Comment: No me muestra más que "Hello,PHP!"

Comment: la zona de respuestas no es espacio para hacerle preguntas al OP sobre su publicación, espera a tener la suficiente reputación y podrás dejarle comentarios, mientras te invito a leer [answer], teniendo la oportunidad de editar y mejorar tu aporte

Comment: ¿Le entendiste a su pregunta "anonimo"?, estoy intentando saber qué intenta hacer para ayudarle.

Comment: Ya actualice mi pregunta amigo @Franco

Comment: No te preocupes por lo que dijo anónimo, si no tienes la reputación necesaria, solo queda escribir como respuesta, a mi también me ha pasado. :)

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal no tener la reputación necesaria no da pie a dejar en la zona de respuestas preguntas, una vez mas no son mis reglas; si aún no pueden dejar comentarios entonces continuen por favor apoyando en otras publicaciones que 50 puntos rapido los alcanzan, por otro lado LUIS comprendo que la pregunta no es clara pero trato de ayudarte a que tu publicación no reciba negativos y en el mejor de los casos algún mod la mueva a la zona de comentarios

Comment: Entiendo, lo bueno es que en stackoverflow meta puedo publicar este caso para ver como se soluciona y no limitar al usuario.

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal http://tpcg.io/CjIEpQ lo agregué por tí, tienes unos tags de php de más sin cerrar el anterior, intenta agregarlos así como te los puse.

Comment: @anonimo, con respecto a la reputación de para comentar, entiendo que por temas de span y palabras que no tengan ningún valor afecten a la plataforma, pero para los usuarios que tienen experiencia como el caso de LUISFRANCO, pienso yo que se debería de tratar este tema de otra forma. Esperemos que se pueda hacer algo más adelante :)

Comment: No no, yo digo a todos en general, eso seria injusto.

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal es lo que me interesaba, última pregunta que respondo en esta plataforma, no hay nada como stack overflow en ingles, no hay muchos que se la lleven de moderadores COMO ESTOS QUE NO AYUDAN EN NADA, éxitos mi hermano.